# Datatables Length Changing Input Control Appears Twice

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I am using DataTables with Bootstrap styling. I'm running into an issue where the length control of the table appears twice, even when leaving it completely out of the dom ([Dom reference](http://datatables.net/reference/option/dom)).

Example of the problem on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/966br7sy/).

Relevant portion of javascript where I manipulate the dom:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({"dom": 
                    "<'row'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6'>>"+
            "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>"+
            "<'row'<'col-sm-12'i>>"+"<'row'<''col-sm-12'>>"});
} );
```

I would like for the length change control to not appear at all.

Comment: Please detail a little. The header appears twice?

Comment: You can see the length change control appearing twice. Once at the top, once at the bottom in the linked jsfiddle

Comment: The limitation for number of elements / page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra `'` in your last `<'row'` tag. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({"dom": 
                    "<'row'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6'>>"+
            "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>"+
            "<'row'<'col-sm-12'i>>"+"<'row'<'col-sm-12'>>"});
} );
```

Updated JS Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/966br7sy/1/).

If you want it not to appear at all, you should remove the `l` in `<'col-sm-6'l>` as well.

Another updated JS Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/966br7sy/6/).

Comment: You beat me to it by a second. Congrats!

Comment: Thanks. You've got mine too.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

I got this fixed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable({"dom": 
                "<'row'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6'>>"+
                "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>"+
                "<'row'<'col-sm-12'i>>"+"<'row'<'col-sm-12'>>"});
```

} );

you actually had a missed `'` over there.